# Unable to open multiple instance of broswer using selenium grid

Tags: selenium

I am  using selenium grid(JUNIT, Java) to run my test case on mutli instance of browser.
I used "java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.20.0.jar -role hub" to run hub.
and "java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.20.0.jar -role webdriver -hub http://`machineip`:4444/grid/register -port 5566" to run node.

I verified that both are running fine.

But when I run testcase through eclipse only one instace of browser opened.

i used this piece of code.

```
    @Test
public void method() throws MalformedURLException {
    baseUrl = "https://www.google.co.in";
    nodeUrl = "http://`machinip`:5566/wd/hub";
    DesiredCapabilities capability = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
    capability.setBrowserName("firefox");
    capability.setPlatform(Platform.WINDOWS);
    driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(nodeUrl), capability);
    // WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get(baseUrl);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td/div/input")).sendKeys("lucky");
}
```

Can please someone suggest how can i open multiple instance for single test.

Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: It looks like you are only creating 1 driver there. I don't see where the two drivers come in.

Comment: Do you mean if i have to run 10 instance i have create 10 drivers??
Can you please provide the code.

Comment: Why don't you try TestNG for this? its easier to do such works ;)

Comment: Thx Prashanth. i will use it. but is there any requirment to change in code??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this tag when starting the server
-browser  maxInstances=5

Answer (score 1):

you test code looks good in general - for a single test)
i think you are missing the way you run the test - if you run it single time it will open a single instance.
in testNg you can run it using dataprovider (parameterized) several times, and specify in testing.xml that you want "parallel=methods", this way all your "parametrized" instances of the test will run together.
also make sure that u have -browser maxInstances=5, in the node start line (or any number that you want).

[efficient selenium testing lab](http://www.ravellosystems.com/blog/build-effective-web-ui-testing-lab/)

[disclosure : i work at Ravello]