# selenium grid not launching multiple browser instances

Tags: selenium-grid, multiple-browsers

Hi I am using `selenium grid 2` version `3.14.0` and I have given the command:

`java -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver="E:/BrowserDrivers/chromedriver.exe" -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.5.1.jar -port 7077 -role node -hub http://172.17.7.20:4444/grid/register -browser "browserName=chrome, version="68.0.3440.106", maxInstances=3, maxSession=3,platform=WIN8_1"`

But it is launching only one instance of chrome browser even though the `maxInstances` was given to `3`.

Comment: please anybody help me i am behind this around 3 days

Comment: Maybe this helps [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19664721/unable-to-open-multiple-instance-of-broswer-using-selenium-grid)

Comment: ok let me try with dataprovider in testng.xml which i have missed

Comment: Anyway milan thanks for the link

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to open multiple instance of broswer using selenium grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19664721/unable-to-open-multiple-instance-of-broswer-using-selenium-grid)

Comment: You're welcome @joe, hope it helps.